# Cannot find reference 'TextVectorization' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, tensorflow2.0

I'm using Pycharm 2021.2.3 with tensorflow 2.6.2 on ubuntu 18.04.6

When testing the Text classification tutorial from https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings

In this line :

`from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization`

I got the error:

Cannot find reference 'TextVectorization' in '**init**.py'

But calling TextVectorization in my model is working. And if I use tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization, again no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I opened an issue on jetbrains
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51709

Answer (score 0):

TextVectorization is found under `tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing`, not `tensorflow.keras.layers`